# Using probability scores from a random forest

Tags: probability, bayesian, random-forest, conditional-probability

I've the following problem. I've a data set that tries to predict whether a given buy event will happen or not (0/1) when a customer sees a certain product, and I've features created for both the customer and the product (I'm excluding the nature of the data set and related matters to keep things simple). I build a classifier (R's random Forest) and conclude the following.

```
             Actual 
             0   1
 Predicted
         0   0.97 0.03
         1   0.13 0.87
```

Separately, I've the priors for the probability of a given product being sold. i.e. number of customers buying a certain product divided by number of customers who got to view that product. My question is two fold

1) When I run the model for a given customer and product combination, I get a probability estimate of buy (given by predict function with type="prob"). How do I blend this with the prior knowledge of the sell through rate of the product?
2) Is this even the right approach to take?

Comment: To keep things simple I would just add the sell through rate of the product to your X variables.  Bayesian updating seems to be what you're asking about, but that would only make sense if you were continually retraining your forest to constantly incorporate new data.  Even then I don't know if random forest and bayesian updating really work well together.

Comment: Why not build a Bayesian logistic regression model, where you can incorporate the prior information into the likelihood function? The prior probabilities can be specified using beta distributions for example and that's basically adding a few successes or failures in the training set. However, there's a lack of way of incorporating that into a random forest model. A weighted blending might be the way to go.